# Filters only working in jqgrid after manually sorting

Tags: jqgrid, filtering

I've got a jqgrid application. I have filters on a left panel (with checkboxes), and the grid in the main panel should list only the filtered rows. It actually works, but only after clicking on the name of a column and sorting the column.

The function that creates the filters is as follows:

```
function filtraTablaElemRegFiltros(filtroZona, filtroEnt,filtroVal){

   filtroORZona={groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
   filtroOREnt={groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
   filtroORVal={groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};

   filtro = {groupOp:"AND",groups:[]};

    var grid = $("#tabla");

    var filtroZonaArray= new Array();
    var filtroEntArray= new Array();
    var filtroValArray= new Array();


    todosElemReg= grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');


    filtroZonaArray=filtroZona.split("-");
    filtroEntArray=filtroEnt.split("-");
    filtroValArray=filtroVal.split("-");

    for(i=1;i<filtroZonaArray.length;i++){
        filtroORZona.rules.push({"field":"nombre","op":"bw","data":filtroZonaArray[i]});
    }
    for(i=1;i<filtroEntArray.length;i++){
        filtroOREnt.rules.push({"field":"entidadCod","op":"eq","data":filtroEntArray[i]});
    }
    for(i=1;i<filtroValArray.length;i++){
        filtroORVal.rules.push({"field":"validado","op":"eq","data":filtroValArray[i]});
    }
    filtro.groups.push(filtroORZona);
    filtro.groups.push(filtroOREnt);
    filtro.groups.push(filtroORVal);

    grid[0].p.search = filtro.groups.length > 0; //busca si filtro no está vacío
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(filtro)});   
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);

}
```

To create the grid:

```
tableToGrid("#tabla",  
    {
        caption:'Lista de elementos de registro',
        datatype:'json',
        mtype:'POST',
        loadonce:true,
        jsonReader:{repeatitems: false, id:"0"},
        url:'json/ElemRegJQGrid.jsp',
        editurl:'json/operacionesElemReg.jsp',
        postData:{codigo_descarga:codigo_descarga,filtroZona:filtroZona,filtroEnt:filtroEnt,filtroVal:filtroVal},

        colNames:[
           'Codigo','Nombre','Latitud','Longitud','Altura','Fecha/hora toma','Comentario', 'Direccion','Numero', 'Serigrafia','Cota','Tipo Registro Codigo','Tipo de registro', 'Entidad codigo','Entidad','Validado' 
        ],

        colModel:[
           {name:'codigo',index:'codigo',editable:false,key:true},      
            {name:'nombre',index:'nombre',editable:true},
            {name:'latitud',index:'latitud',editable:false,editrules:{required:true},width:'100'},
            {name:'longitud',index:'longitud',editable:false,editrules:{required:true},width:'100'},
            {name:'altura',index:'altura',editable:false,formatoptions:{defaulvalue:0},width:'75'},
            {name:'fecha',index:'fecha',editable:false,sorttype:'date',align:'center',width:'250',formatter:'datetime', formatoptions:{srcFormat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',newformat: 'd-m-Y'}, searchoptions:{dataInit:datePick, attr:{title:'Elija Fecha'}},editoptions:{dataInit:datePick}},
            {name:'comentario',index:'comentario',editable:true},
            {name:'direccion',index:'direccion',editable:true},
            {name:'direccion_numero',index:'direccion_numero',formater:'integer',editable:true, width:'70', defaultvalue:0},
            {name:'serigrafia',index:'serigrafia',editable:true, formater:'text',width:'120'},
            {name:'cota',index:'cota',editable:true,formater:'integer', defaultvalue:0, width:'50'},
            {name:'tipoelemregCod',index:'tipoelemregCod',hidden:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:'json/tiposElemReg.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'json/tiposElemReg.jsp'}},
            {name:'tipoelemregNom',index:'tipoelemregNom',stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:'json/tiposElemReg.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'json/tiposElemReg.jsp'}},
            {name:'entidadCod',index:'entidadCod',hidden:true,stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp'}},
            {name:'entidadNom',index:'entidadNom',stype:'select',searchoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp',searchhidden:true},editable:true,edittype:'select',editoptions:{dataUrl:'json/entidades.jsp'}},
            {name:'validado',index:'validado',editable:false, width:'50',cellattr: 
                    function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                        var color = "";

                        switch (val){
                            case  "VALIDO":
                                    color="green";
                                    break;
                           case "INVALIDO":
                                    color="red";
                                    break;
                            case "PENDIENTE": 
                                    color="yellow";
                                    break;

                            }

                        return 'style="background-color:' + color +'" title="'+val+'"';
                    }
             }


        ],

        sortable:true,        
        height:'auto',
        pager:jQuery('#navegacion'),

        viewrecords:true,
        rowNum:25,
        rowList:[10,15,20,25,50,75,100,150,200,500,1000,2500],

        multiselect:'true',
        cellEdit: true,
        cellurl:'json/operacionesElemRegCellEdit.jsp',
  ondblClickRow:sacaMapaWPTUnico


  });
 loadComplete: filtraTablaElemRegFiltros(filtroZona,filtroEnt,filtroVal);



}
```

And the left panel html includes:

```
<div id="validacion">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="valSelect" id="VALIDO" onclick="filtrarContenido()" /><label for="VALIDO">Validado</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="valSelect" id="INVALIDO" onclick="filtrarContenido()" /><label for="INVALIDO">Invalidado</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="valSelect" id="PENDIENTE" onclick="filtrarContenido()" /><label for="PENDIENTE">Pendiente</label>
                </div>
```

The function filtrarContenido() calls the main panel url and sends in the GET argument the checked boxes:

```
function filtrarContenido(){
    var valorZona="";
    var valorEnt="";
    var valorVal="";


    $("input:checkbox[name=zonaSelect]:checked").each(function() {
        valorZona=valorZona+"-"+$(this).attr('id');
    });
   $("input:checkbox[name=entSelect]:checked").each(function() {
        valorEnt=valorEnt+"-"+$(this).attr('id');
    });
    $("input:checkbox[name=valSelect]:checked").each(function() {
        valorVal=valorVal+"-"+$(this).attr('id');
    });

    urlPrincipal=document.getElementById("principal").contentWindow.location.href;

    posArgumentos=urlPrincipal.search('codigo_descarga');

    if(posArgumentos!='-1') urlPrincipal=urlPrincipal.substring(0,posArgumentos-1);

    urlNueva=urlPrincipal+'?codigo_descarga=0'+'&'+'filtroZona='+valorZona+'&'+'filtroEnt='+valorEnt+'&'+'filtroVal='+valorVal;


    document.getElementById("principal").contentWindow.location.href=urlNueva;

}
```

Can anyone help me? Why is not showing the filtered data after clicking on the checkboxes? It is actually filtering them, but it doesn't show them until clicking on sorting columns.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I just realized it also works if before reloading the grid I show an alert window. Weird...

Comment: I'm still having this problem. Can anyone give me a clue? Thanks!